# How to set component Focus on load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a situation that happens in several of my components, where I show a new component, that is absolutely positioned and has an input control. I am using some basic logic to set the input control to set focus, which it does successfully.

When the control pops up, I can start typing right away as expected. However, if I click the "Tab" key, in this specific scenario, it navigates the underlying component to the next cell in the grid, instead of the top level div tab control.

However, If I click into the input box on this page with a mouse click, and then type, the tab key works as expected, as it appears the top level component/div does not have focus even though the input control does? Considering the input already has focus, I"m not sure what clicking into the input does, but it effectively solves my issue.

So, what is the difference in setting focus on the input versus clicking into this input box? Is there a way to programmatically give this input the focus it gets that matches clicking into it with mouse?

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for refs . Please check if this is what you need https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: I'm using a Ref to set focus on the input control...which works great. But the "tab", "enter" keys, etc are still connected to underlying grid control. I don't understand what happens when I click into the input control that is different from using the ref to set focus, but it behaves differently.

Comment: this sounds interesting. Could you perhaps show us the method for using the ref to focus the input?